# multi-screen switcher

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, hotkeys

I have a windows 7 machine with vmware and 2 monitors.
The first one, with vmware on fullscreen, and the second one as the main screen with windows 7 with the browser and some applications, is there any way to toggle the screens configuration with a hotkey so it switches the main screen to the left and all applications accordingly (Vmware on full screen on the right monitor, and all applications on the left)

Comment: With Windows+P you can switch through the differents modes of multiscreen, but I'm not sure it does exactly the way you want it.

Comment: no, actually that's what i find everyone talking about, i want to keep them as extend, but switch what's on the right screen to the left screen, and what's on the left screen to the right

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but winsplit revolution is fairly usefull for moving windows around.
( FreeWare :  http://www.winsplit-revolution.com )

Answer (score 0):

You can "throw" the active window from one screen to another by depressing Windows Key + Shift key and then left or right arrow key depending upon which monitor you want the window to go to.

I know that you you are asking to change the main display designator but I don't think there is a hot key for that. You have to go into "screen resolution" and then check the box marked "Make this my main display" after selecting the appropriate display.